# how to handle box background color for multiples time function refreshing in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
function first(Objs) {            
         var imgid= Objs;                
         secondMethod(imgid);             

     }

function secondmethod(imgid) {
        var boxid=imgid.id;
        var color = getBackgroundColor(imgid.status);//am passing different colors for every refreshing(i.e. #D03C78 or #B8B8B8) values from DataBase 
        if($('#boxcontent'+boxid).is(':visible')) {
        }else{
    var boxText = document.createElement("div");
    boxText.id='boxcontent'+boxid;
    boxText.style.cssText = "white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;border:2px solid ;background-color:"+color+";opacity:0.9;filter:alpha(opacity=90);-moz-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px;color:black !important;";
    return boxText;
        }
        $('#boxcontent'+boxid).css({'background-color':color});

     }
```

- this box content is displaying on map.
- this box background color not getting in IE,but works in FireFox,
- this first function refreshing every 10 seconds with different objts.(for every refreshing changing color).
- in IE not working(i.e. color not changing),please help for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- check is it refreshing in every 10 seconds.
- you said that for every 10 seconds will get different objects.
- IE may get problem with resending data(when refreshing) i.e caching problem.

`var color = getBackgroundColor(imgid.status);//am passing different colors for every refreshing(i.e. #D03C78 or #B8B8B8) values from DataBase 
alert(imgid.id+" : color is : "+color)`

- lets check this one in Firefox and IE.

Comment: yes in IE not changed,i got this alert values: **bold** `101 : color is : #D03C78`  i changed in DB this id status then after refreshing got **bold** `101: color is : #D03C78`.

Answer (score 0):

its hard to tell, why IE not setting the color with the information you gave...
might be also a css error or missing commas etc.
But ill try to help you out.. 
You have a strange mix in JS and JQuery, so i tried to merge this to jQuery, as it
proviedes some X-Browser stuff for IE.. 
Also i made a class, because its more clean like this.

```
//Some definition
var Objs = {
    id : 'test',
    status : "red"
};
//Call
first(Objs);

function first(Objs) {            
    var imgid= Objs;                
    secondMethod(imgid);             
}

function secondMethod(imgid) {
    var boxid = imgid.id;
    var color = imgid.status;

    if($('#boxcontent' + boxid).length < 1) { //No existing box, make new
        var boxText = $("<div></div>")
            .attr("id", "boxcontent"+boxid)
            .addClass("basciStyleNoColor")
            .css({
                'background-color' : color,
                opacity : 0.9 //<<-- Jquery sets filter for IE...
            });

        $("body").append(boxText);//<<-Insert here, or retrun and insert later...
        return boxText;
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.basciStyleNoColor {
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-align:center;
    border:2px solid ;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color:black !important;    
}
```

here the [Fiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/4VLvS/)

hope it helps some how...